# How to Combine Formulas with Blanks in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to setup a simple spreadsheet to track sales, inventory, etc.  The columns are Item, Purchase Cost (C), for how much they will list the item, for how much it actually sells (G), the commission cost for their reseller (H), if a credit card is used (I), if a card is used then what that charge amount is (J), and then finally a profit overall (K).

I am using:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(G2)), "", G2-C2)
```

to populate H, this is great because it leaves the column blank if nothing is entered in purchase or sale columns.  I am doing similar things for other columns, which all work except for one.  Under the CC Charge column (J), I am using:

```
=IF(I2="yes", G2*0.02,"")
```

For the profit column (K), I am using:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(G2)), "", G2-C2-J2)
```

However, that only works if there is a value added under (J).  If no credit card is used, then the formula should only be G2-C2, but I can't figure out how to keep the cells blank if no other data is used.

TL;DR: I want to format a cell so that it will remain blank unless data is entered in other columns.  If so, I want have an IF function that says something like:

```
=IF(I2="yes", G2-C2-J2, G2-C2)
```

How can I combine these formulas?

Comment: I don’t have access to excel at the moment to build this exactly as you need but you need a second IF embedded into the very last formula you listed.

Comment: @fix, that's the right approach, however since there is a formula in the Col J which evaluates to "" (a blank value), when we use the formula G2-C2-J2, this gets evaluated to `3-2-""`, which results in a #VALUE! error. To avoid this, I have proposed to use a ISNUMBER check on Col J in my answer below. Also, another method would have been to simply modify the formula in column J to `=IF(I2="yes", G2*0.02,)`. This way J2 will always result in a number and G2-C2-J2 will always evaluate to the correct `Profit Overall`

Comment: @BharatAnand, you're right if a null has been stored in J2.  My read was that J2 is simply empty until a value is put there.  If that's the case, the formula doesn't need to jump through hoops.  If you add that case to your answer, I'll upvote it.  The OP may simply be overthinking the problem.

Comment: @fix, indeed this is a much neater solution with much simplified formulaes. But if we go ahead and modify the original formula in Col J, and change it to something like this - `=IF(I2="yes", G2*0.02,"")`, it results in displaying a 0 in Col J. This would contradict with the original requirement to "... leave the column blank ..." and "I am doing similar things for other columns ...". And hence I prefer to keep the answer as what I have posted. Feel free to upvote, I have carefully thought thru the requirements and adequately tested it at my end ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some clearly written rules to solve this problem easily. The below statement is good overall requirement but still a little vague.

> I want to format a cell so that it will remain blank unless data is entered in other columns

Let's say the rules are as below:

**Rule#1**: `Col J` (CC charge)

- If `Col I` is yes, then calculate `Col J` (CC charge), else keep it blank

**Rule#2**: `Col K` Overall Profit

- If `Col J` is *not blank*, then calculate it as `G2-C2-J2`
- If `Col J` is *blank*, then calculate it as `G2-C2`

---

**Solution:**

Your current formula in Col J already satisfies Rule#1.

```
=IF(I2="yes", G2*0.02,"")
```

To satisfy Rule#2, you can use the below formula,

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(J2), G2-C2-J2, G2-C2)
```

The question mentions needing to combine this with testing other cells for blanks, so just replace G2-C2 references with H2 as below:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(J2), H2-J2, H2)
```

Comment: @fixer1234, all yours!

Comment: I reread the question, and had missed the part about J2 containing a null.  You were right.  I just rolled it back to your version.  Nevermind.  :-)  (and I upvoted it)

Comment: @fixer1234, the last point is also not required, in fact while debating this internally I figured out that all references of G2-C2 need to be replaced with H2, as we have already taken that efforts to calculate the commission column earlier. I will modify the answer again and hopefully put this to bed now! :-)

Comment: This is making my brain hurt, but I think your last formula may suffer from the original problem, H2 can contain a null, so H2-J2 could result in an error.